# What does $ means in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I stumbled across [this article](https://www.quora.com/In-which-programming-languages-is-Ke-ha-a-valid-identifier) in Quota, and saw this code snipped. However, I couldn't find much information about it.

```
def Ke(x)
  "called Ke with param #{x}"
end

$ Ke 'sha'
=> "Called Ke with param sha"

$ Ke$ha
=> "Called Ke with param "

$ Ke$overwhaterver
=> "Called Ke with param "
```

Why does calling `Ke$ha` called the function `Ke(x)`, but it also ignore the `x` parameter?

Comment: Pretty sure something like this has been asked before, but Stack Overflow seems to make it impossible to search for `$` ... >_<

Comment: @Carpetsmoker yeah, seems so. Maybe that's the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `$` you can access global variables. Ruby automatically adds the parenthesis. It's the same as using `Ke($ha)` or `Ke $ha`.

Global variables can always be referenced without error; they default to `nil`:

```
$zxc # => nil
$zxc = 'asd'
$zxc # => "asd"
```

The parameter `$ha` isn't "ignored", it's `nil`, and `nil.to_s` is an empty string.

Comment: and why doesn't we need to put space between `Ke` and `$ha`?

Comment: @Azuan Ruby's parser is pretty flexible. Since the `$` can only appear at the beginning of a global variable, it "knows" a new token starts. Would be the same with an uninitialized instance var: `Ke@x #=> nil`